# How to hike the salary of the employees based on their departments in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects consisting of employee details like *salary*, *name*, *dept* and *id*.

JS:

```
$scope.filteredDept = [];

$scope.employees = [
    {'id':1, 'dept': 'IT', 'sal': 5000, 'name': 'ramesh'},
    {'id':2, 'dept': 'IT', 'sal': 4000, 'name': 'Girish'},
    {'id':3, 'dept': 'Management', 'sal': 10000, 'name': 'Kartik'},
    {'id':4, 'dept': 'Marketing', 'sal': 8000, 'name': 'Shenoy'},
    {'id':5, 'dept': 'Marketing', 'sal': 7000, 'name': 'Darvik'},
    {'id':6, 'dept': 'Management', 'sal': 17000, 'name': 'Ravi Kumar'}
];
$scope.empFiltered = $scope.employees;
$scope.departments = [
    {'id':1, 'name':'IT','selected':false},
    {'id':2, 'name':'Management','selected':false},
    {'id':3, 'name':'Marketing','selected':false}
];

$scope.sortEmp = function(dept_id){
    $scope.bool = $scope.departments.filter(function(e){
        if(e.id === dept_id){
            var idx = $scope.filteredDept.indexOf(e.name,0);
            if(idx === -1){
                $scope.filteredDept.push(e.name);
                $scope.filterEmpList();
                return 0;
            }
            else {
                $scope.filteredDept.splice(idx,1);
                $scope.filterEmpList();
                return 0;
            }
        }
    });
};
$scope.filterEmpList = function(){
    $scope.filteredData = [];
    if($scope.filteredDept.length !==0){
        $scope.empFiltered = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.filteredDept, function(val,key){
            $scope.filteredData = $scope.employees.filter(function(e){
                if(e.dept === val){
                 return e;
                } 
            });
            angular.forEach($scope.filteredData, function(v,k){
                $scope.empFiltered.push(v);
            });               
        });
    }
    else{
        $scope.empFiltered = $scope.employees;
    }       
};
```

HTML:

```
Hike percentage : <input type="number" ng-model="hike"/>
<button>Hike the salary</button>
<br>
Hike by dept : <br>
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="dept in departments track by $index">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="dept.selected" ng-click="sortEmp(dept.id)"/> {{dept.name}}
  </label>
</div>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
            <th>Dept</th>
            <th>Hike Percentage</th>
            <th>Hike Amount</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="emp in empFiltered track by $index">
          <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.dept}}</td>
            <td>hike percentage</td>
            <td>hike amount</td>
            <td>{{emp.sal | currency: '&#8360; '}}</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Here, i am selecting dept to filter the employees table based on the selected checkbox.

I want to increase the salary based on the department and the hike percentage from the input box.

I am not getting how to achieve it. can i get any help or guidance.

Comment: You can use Javascript `map` method to do this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a function to do hike the salary of the employees and then apply the map

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   
    $scope.filteredDept = [];
    
    $scope.employees = [
     {'id':1, 'dept': 'IT', 'sal': 5000, 'name': 'ramesh'},
        {'id':2, 'dept': 'IT', 'sal': 4000, 'name': 'Girish'},
        {'id':3, 'dept': 'Management', 'sal': 10000, 'name': 'Kartik'},
        {'id':4, 'dept': 'Marketing', 'sal': 8000, 'name': 'Shenoy'},
        {'id':5, 'dept': 'Marketing', 'sal': 7000, 'name': 'Darvik'},
        {'id':6, 'dept': 'Management', 'sal': 17000, 'name': 'Ravi Kumar'}
    ];
    $scope.empFiltered = $scope.employees;
    $scope.departments = [
     {'id':1, 'name':'IT','selected':false},
        {'id':2, 'name':'Management','selected':false},
        {'id':3, 'name':'Marketing','selected':false}
    ];
    
    $scope.sortEmp = function(dept_id){
     $scope.bool = $scope.departments.filter(function(e){
         if(e.id === dept_id){
                var idx = $scope.filteredDept.indexOf(e.name,0);
                if(idx === -1){
                 $scope.filteredDept.push(e.name);
                    $scope.filterEmpList();
                    return 0;
                }
                else {
                 $scope.filteredDept.splice(idx,1);
                    $scope.filterEmpList();
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });
    };
    $scope.filterEmpList = function(){
     $scope.filteredData = [];
  if($scope.filteredDept.length !==0){
         $scope.empFiltered = [];
         angular.forEach($scope.filteredDept, function(val,key){
             $scope.filteredData = $scope.employees.filter(function(e){
                    if(e.dept === val){
                     return e;
                    } 
                });
    angular.forEach($scope.filteredData, function(v,k){
                 $scope.empFiltered.push(v);
                });               
            });
        }
        else{
         $scope.empFiltered = $scope.employees;
        }     
    };
    $scope.hikeSal = function(){
     var arr = [];
        arr = $scope.empFiltered.map(function(e){
         if(e.hike === undefined){
             e.hike = 0;
            }
         e.hike = parseInt(e.hike) + $scope.hike;
            e.hikeAmt = e.sal * ($scope.hike * 0.01);
         e.sal += e.sal * ($scope.hike * 0.01);
            //return e;
        });
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
ercentage : <input type="number" ng-model="hike"/>
<button ng-click="hikeSal()">Hike the salary</button>
<br>
Hike by dept : <br>
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="dept in departments track by $index">
  <label>
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="dept.selected" ng-click="sortEmp(dept.id)"/> {{dept.name}}
  </label>
</div>
<table border='1'>
 <thead>
     <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
            <th>Dept</th>
            <th>Hike Percentage</th>
            <th>Hike Amount</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="emp in empFiltered track by $index">
         <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.dept}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.hike}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.hikeAmt}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.sal | currency: '&#8360; '}}</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like `employees.filter(e => e.dpt === department).forEach(e => e.sal = e.sal * (1+hikePercent))`, obviously modify to your needs

The first part is for filtering the list of employees to ones with the correct department, and then you forEach over that filtered list to change their salary.

-- edit -- https://jsfiddle.net/zd3vxpka/

Comment: Thanks for your reply but am not getting how to do this.

Comment: @Rocky you can see in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zd3vxpka/) that I set a salary multiplier and a filter, and use the code I gave you, modified slightly, to change the salaries of the employees who match the filter.

Comment: Thans for your responce

Answer (score 0):

First you'll want to put an ng-click directive on the button. Assign it to a scope function on the controller just like you did for the checkbox. You already have the hike % bound so you can use that anywhere in the controller. You have dept.selected already so you know which is selected. So then based on all that information, inside the ng-click function you make on the button you can filter the array and make the change.

```
<button ng-click="hikePay()">Hike the salary</button>

$scope.hikePay = function(){
   // use bound variables to manipulate the array
}
```